# Bounds cointegration with dLagM

Tags: r, cointegration, bounds, ardl

I am testing for cointegration relationships using various procedures, including bounds cointegration, which I am not very familiar with, both in terms of theory and application. I am currently using the dLagM package in R.

I believe the ardlBound function in this package performs the first step of Pesaran et al. (2001)'s ARDL bounds test in that it tests the valid exclusion of lagged level variables using an F-test (with a non-standard distribution). Is there a way to retrieve the critical values for the F-test from the resulting object?